# Navigate to new page in Ionic-V1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on a project using Ionic v1. I have multiple user type in the project, wherein every user type must be redirected to a different page based on their time. I am unable to achieve this. Here is my code:

app.js:

```
.state('tab.login', {
url: '/login',
views: {
  'tab-login': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  }
 }
})
.state('guest.home' , {
  url: '/guesthome',
  views: {
    'guest-home': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/guest-home.html',
      controller: 'GuestCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('agent.home' , {
  url: '/agenthome',
  views: {
    'agent-home': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/agent-home.html',
      controller: 'AgentCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

controller.js:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  $scope.userLogin = function(email, password) {
  Backendless.UserService.login( $scope.email, $scope.password, true )
  .then( $scope.userLoggedIn )
  .catch ( $scope.gotError )
}

$scope.userLoggedIn = function( user ) {
console.log("User has logged in");
if ( user.user_type === "g" )
  $state.go('guest.home');
else
  $state.go('agent.home');
}

$scope.gotError = function( err ) {
console.log( "error message - " + err.message );
    console.log( "error code - " + err.statusCode );
}

})
```

tabs-login.html:

```
<ion-content class="padding" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
    <span class="input-label">Email</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
    <span class="input-label">Password</span>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
  </label>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
  <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="userLogin()">
    Login
  </button>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

I'm getting the error `error message - Could not resolve 'guest.home' from state 'tab.login'` What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem might be related to the fact that you use dots on your state names, without defining an abstract state to hold children.

Give it a shot without the dots ('guesthome' maybe?), or change your routing to have abstract states.

Here's an example:

```
        $stateProvider
        .state('setup', {
            url: '/setup',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'js/views/setupView.html',
            controller: 'SetupController'
        })
        .state('setup.bluetooth', {
            url: '/bluetooth',
            views: {
                'setupContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'js/views/bluetoothSetupView.html',
                    controller: 'BluetoothSetupController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('setup.truck', {
            url: '/truck',
            views: {
                'setupContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'js/views/truckSetupView.html',
                    controller: 'TruckSetupController'
                }
            }
        })
```